# Haven't received Windows 10 creators update - Intel i7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, hp-pavilion, intel-core-i7

I have Hp Dv6t that was released in 2011. The laptop has

- Intel i7 2670qm
- AMD 6700m GPU
- Samsung 850 evo 256GB SSD
- 8 GB ram

I use this computer for professional work and app development. So security updates and updated OS is crucial along stability.

However I still haven't received the Creators Update. I have been religiously clicking "Check Update" button in Settings but so far nothing appeared.

I read somewhere that Microsoft withheld the update on certain older computers for some reason, however considering PC standards, my machine isn't that old. So when would I receive the Creators Update?

Has anyone here with similar machine or i7 Sandy Bridge processor manual or automatically updated to Windows 10 Creators update?

Comment: 1703 is only being rolled to known compatible configurations through Windows Update.  If you don't want to wait until your configuration is known as being compatible, then you should deploy it yourself manualy with the Upgrade Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the installation of the Windows 10 Creator's update with the [Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

However, the Creator's Update isnt necessarily more stable or secure.  Newer is not always better...

Comment: I would vote it up if you would also mention that this link is present in the Windows Update Settings screen.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing is probably the same problem that happened with the release of the free upgrade to Windows 10; they can't push the update out to enough people in time.  If you want to download and manually install the update, you can do so by going to [Microsoft's Download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), and selecting your version from the list.

Now, as far as your statement:

> I read somewhere that Microsoft withheld the update on certain older computers for some reason, however considering PC standards, my machine isn't that old.

Five years is actually quite old, and could be a factor.  Even discounting gaming requirements (which require new builds every six months to run newer games), you would notice older computers struggle to keep up with some simple applications.